# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'example@gmail.com' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to make custom forgot password in Laravel. I change mail in .env like this:

```
   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
   MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
   MAIL_PORT=465
   MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com
   MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=gmail@gmail.com
```

web.php

```
     Route::get('forget-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 
     'showForgetPasswordForm'])->name('forget.password.get');
      Route::post('forget-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 
      'submitForgetPasswordForm'])->name('forget.password.post'); 
       Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 
     'showResetPasswordForm'])->name('reset.password.get');
      Route::post('reset-password', [ForgotPasswordController::class,  
        'submitResetPasswordForm'])->name('reset.password.post');
```

ForgotPasswordController.php

```
           <?php 

               namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth; 

                use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
             use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
             use DB; 
            use Carbon\Carbon; 
          use App\Models\User; 
         use Mail;
           use Hash;
               use Illuminate\Support\Str;

                class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
       {
  /**
   * Write code on Method
   *
   * @return response()
   */
  public function showForgetPasswordForm()
  {
     return view('auth.forgetPassword');
  }

  /**
   * Write code on Method
   *
   * @return response()
   */
  public function submitForgetPasswordForm(Request $request)
  {
      $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
      ]);

      $token = Str::random(64);

      DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
          'email' => $request->email, 
          'token' => $token, 
          'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

      Mail::send('email.forgetPassword', ['token' => $token], function($message) use($request){
          $message->to($request->email);
          $message->subject('Reset Password');
      });

      return back()->with('message', 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!');
  }
  /**
   * Write code on Method
   *
   * @return response()
   */
  public function showResetPasswordForm($token) { 
     return view('auth.forgetPasswordLink', ['token' => $token]);
  }

  /**
      * Write code on Method
   *
   * @return response()
   */
          public function submitResetPasswordForm(Request $request)
     {
      $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
          'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
          'password_confirmation' => 'required'
      ]);

      $updatePassword = DB::table('password_resets')
                          ->where([
                            'email' => $request->email, 
                            'token' => $request->token
                          ])
                          ->first();

      if(!$updatePassword){
          return back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Invalid token!');
      }

      $user = User::where('email', $request->email)
                  ->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);

      DB::table('password_resets')->where(['email'=> $request->email])->delete();

      return redirect('/login')->with('message', 'Your password has been changed!');
       }
       }
```

forgetPassword.blade.php

```
                                                   <main class="login-form">
                 <div class="cotainer">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Reset Password</div>
                <div class="card-body">

                  @if (Session::has('message'))
                       <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                          {{ Session::get('message') }}
                      </div>
                  @endif

                    <form action="{{ route('forget.password.post') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md- 
                      right">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" 
                            name="email" required autofocus>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }} 
                         </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Send Password Reset Link
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         </div>
           </div>
             </main>
```

Actually i have in database table email, token, created_at. I do not know why this error is. please help. I searched a lot in google but did not find solution which work.

Comment: Can you point out, which line the error is ocuring on?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using Laravel's built-in [Password reset links](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords#password-reset-link-handling-the-form-submission)? That will handle the insertion and updating of reset links, as well as the sending of the email. Otherwise `DB::table('password_resets')->insert([` is going to try to insert even if the email already exists in the database, hence the error.

Comment: @aynber and what is solution? what shoul i make?

Comment: Read the link, it shows an example.

Comment: @aynber can you say to me what should i make?

Answer (score 0):

In your `password_resets` table you have declared the `email` column as the primary key. Each row of the table must therefore have a different `email` value in it. Your error message comes from your MySQL or MariaDb server, and tells you that you tried to insert a duplicate value.

Defining `email` as the primary key means you can have only one password-reset operation in flight at a time for each distinct email address. That's good application design: it will slow down cybercriminals who try to use your password-reset system to break your security.  But, to do this right you need to catch the error and show something useful to the end user like "we already sent you a password-reset link."

You didn't show us your table definition. So, it's hard to give you more specific advice about fixing this problem.

Comment: and what is solutio?

Comment: Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->primary();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });

Comment: this is my table in database